# Arbitrarily place text inside an input field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to Rails and coding in general and struggling to find a solution for what would seem like a fairly straight forward problem, despite some intense googling.  I'm hoping the community can point me in the direction of some further reading or proposed solutions:

I've got an application that basically allows a user to fill out a form.  The form is rendered in the background as a .jpg with a `z-index` of -1(the forms are dependents of the sender) and I would like for a user to be able to place text in any arbitrary place within an input field.  That location should be stored in the DB or otherwise remembered so that it can be rendered in the correct place when using the `show` view.

I'm allowing senders to upload their own forms, so simply placing a form field in the right place won't work.

It would seem that there would be some sort of elegant javascript solution, I just can't seem to find any information on it.

Proposed solutions or further reading are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to save data as soon as user write ? If so, you can use best_in_place gem, it will help to to save data as soon as user types.link - https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place. Or Do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I'm understanding you correctly. when you say that "the form" is rendered in the background, you're referring to a physical form...like something you'd find printed on a sheet of paper, not the HTML "thing" called a form?

If my understanding of that is correct, it sounds like what you'd like is to allow the user to type text "over" the image, in arbitrary locations corresponding to the physical location of printed fields on your image?  Kind of like an editable PDF works?

After giving it a little thought and not coming up with any bleeding obvious ways of tackling it, the best general advice I can give is for you to look in to the HTML 5 Canvas element.  It would probably take some JS magic, but it might be fairly simple to set these uploaded forms up as the "background image" of a canvas which allowed the user to type arbitrary things on to it.  From there, I'm sure there are reasonable ways to save the "state" of a canvas such that it could be transmitted to a server-side persistence layer of some kind.

Comment: Apologies for the delay - you're correct - when I was referring to as a "form" I meant a physical document, not the HTML object called form.  I've researched the canvas element as suggested, but all signs are pointing towards drawing rather than text input.